# How to block import of specific python package?

Tags: python, python-import

I need to programmatically block import of a python package and all child packages.

For example, I need to block loading of the package "foo" and also ensure that all children of foo such as "foo.bar" cannot be imported.

How can this be achieved in python 2.x without restructuring my site packages or PYTHONPATH?

For context, the intent is to programmatically avoid the risk of importing proprietary code into GPL licensed code.

Comment: I sense an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What do you expect if `import foo` is called, raise an exception?

Comment: just add an empty foo.py right next to the main entry point of the script (ie main.py) or put a `raise Exception("No Foo allowed")` in the file

Comment: Not to say you can't do it, but won't someone promptly fork your GPL code and remove the restriction? Or are you doing it to help you develop without accidentally using packages you don't want dependencies on? In which case I'd have thought the "right" approach is to set up a test environment that doesn't have the packages you want to avoid.

Comment: Fair point Steve.

My goal is to prevent accidental inclusion by developers who may not be paying attention to where they are in the codebase. Raising an exception analogous to mistyping a module name is the best I could hope for.
In an ideal world I'd use two separate source repos and separate build systems for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not fit your solution *exactly* but you can simply mock out the entire module so the module and all of it's submodules have no effect:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to mock an entire module ? Thanks